# PnP FieldUserRenderer control and value prop

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, pnp

I developed a web part where I am using [FieldUserRenderer control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/fields/FieldUserRenderer/) and the field does not completely work how it should be based on documentation.

In my case, when I hover the mouse pointer on the person, the popup has an infinite spinner:

[image]

Code:

```
public readonly peopleRegisterFields: IViewField[] = [
{
  name: 'RCPDUrl',
  displayName: 'Nazwa rejestru',
  minWidth: 180,
  isResizable: true,
  sorting: true,
  render: (item) => {
    return <FieldUrlRenderer
      text={item['RCPDUrl.Description']} url={item['RCPDUrl.Url']}
    />;
  }
},
{
  name: 'Worker',
  displayName: 'Pracownik',
  minWidth: 150,
  isResizable: true,
  sorting: true,
  render: (item) => {
    let user: Array<IPrincipal> = [{
      id: item['Pracownik.Id'],
      email: item['Pracownik.EMail'],
      department: item['Pracownik.Department'],
      jobTitle: item['Pracownik.JobTitle'],
      sip: item['Pracownik.SipAddress'],
      title: item['Pracownik.Title'],
      value: '',
      picture: ''
    }];
    return <FieldUserRenderer users={user} context={this.props.context} />;
  }
},
```

And rest quest for getting people from list:

```
 jquery.ajax({
    url: `https://.....sharepoint.com/sites/.././_api/web/lists/getbyId('` + webPart.props.peopleRegisterListId + `')/items?$top=5000&$select=RCPDUrl,Id,Data_x0020_upowa_x017c_nienia,Author/Id,Author/EMail,Author/Department,Author/JobTitle,Author/SipAddress,Author/Title,Editor/Id,Editor/EMail,Editor/Department,Editor/JobTitle,Editor/SipAddress,Editor/Title,Modified,Created,Pracownik/Id,Pracownik/EMail,Pracownik/Department,Pracownik/JobTitle,Pracownik/SipAddress,Pracownik/Title,DataNadaniaUprawnien,DataAnulowaniaUprawnien&$expand=Author/Id,Editor/Id,Pracownik/Id`,
    type: "GET",
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;' },
    success: function (resultData) {
      let _i: number = resultData.d.results.length;
      webPart.setState({
        peopleRegister: resultData.d.results,
        peopleRegisterItemsCount: _i,
        peopleRegisterPageCount: Math.round(_i / 20),
      });
    },
    error: function () { }
  });
```

I used that code because in this way I don't need to use sp.web.siteUsers and sp.web.person to get information like job title or deprameten.

I have no idea what I must put in value, I assume the missing value of value may be the issue, but I cannot find any examples of what should be there.

Comment: Can you please add to / edit your post so that the code defining ‘Pracownik’ can be viewed?

Comment: @A.k.A.Fritz added I'm completely newbie in spfx/typescript, so my code may be kind of strange by work ;)

Comment: I get that, I’m trying to help.  Please, can you display your entire script - redacting all personally identifiable information and domain names?

Comment: Because is long, I put it here https://textuploader.com/18qpp